Unable to Update Entry in Contentful with Next.js: "Access token invalid" Error
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to update an entry in Contentful using the Contentful Management SDK. I've followed the example provided in the documentation, but I keep receiving an "Access token invalid" error, despite being certain that the access token is correct.
import { createClient } from 'contentful-management'

const client = createClient({
    accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN,
  }, 
  {
    type: 'plain',
    defaults: {
      spaceId: SPACE_ID,
      environmentId: 'master',
    },
  }
)

const entries = await client.entry.getMany({
  query: {
    limit: 200
  }
})


AccessTokenInvalid: {
  "status": 401,
  "statusText": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Access token invalid",
  "details": {},
  "request": {
    "url": "/spaces/SPACE_ID/environments/master/entries",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/vnd.contentful.management.v1+json",
      "X-Contentful-User-Agent": "sdk contentful-management-plain.js/11.5.1; platform node.js/v20.10.0; os macOS/v20.10.0;",
      "Authorization": "Bearer ...lMH1I",
      "User-Agent": "axios/1.6.1",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br"
    },
    "method": "get"
  },
  "requestId": "aa75be62-2fa1-4d64-a78a-65ea605dce9b"
}

Any help or suggestions on resolving this issue specific to Next.js would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

is ACCESS_TOKEN a variable somewhere?

Yes, it's in env. This variable returns the value. I checked it.

have you tried to pasting the raw value itself to see if it worked? Could be an issue with your environment variables being loaded

Of course, I tried to paste the raw value. The issue is not with it.

the problem is solved. I needed to use personal access token, but I used Content Delivery API - access token.
